# Webpack ExtractTextPlugin - avoid duplicate classes in output css

Tags: webpack, sass, sass-loader, extract-text-plugin

I'm building a react app and im using webpack 3 with css/sass loaders + the ExtractTextPlugin to compile my styles and generate main.css. All my scss variables, mixins and partials are compiling into one single main.css file, but **my problem is that im getting duplicate classes in main.css**.

I have a main.scss where I import all of my variables, mixins and partials. Im also using the underscore prefix for all of my partials, variables etc.

I cant figure out what the problem is!

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: './src/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});
const output = path.resolve(__dirname + '/dist/');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/js/index.js',
  output: {
    path: output,
    filename: 'js/index.bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.scss$/, use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        use: [{
          loader: 'css-loader',
        },
        {
          loader: 'sass-loader'
        }]
      })
    }]
  },
  plugins: [
    HtmlWebpackPluginConfig,
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: 'css/main.css',
      disable: false,
      allChunks: true
    })
  ]
}
```

**_button.scss**

```
@import '../base/variables.scss';
@import '../base/mixins.scss';

.button {
  border: 3px solid $red;
  background-color: $white;
  color: $red;
  border-radius: 25px;
  @include size(160px, 55px);  
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all 800ms $expo-ease-out;

  &:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }

  @include breakpoint(mobile) {
    @include size(150px, 50px);
  }
}
```

**main.scss**

```
@import 'base/variables.scss';
@import 'base/mixins.scss';
@import 'base/typography.scss';
@import 'base/global.scss';
@import 'base/ui.scss';

@import 'components/button.scss';
@import 'components/header.scss';
// etc
```

all of my classes are duplicated in the output css:
**main.css**

```
.button {
  border: 3px solid #810409;
  background-color: #FFFCF2;
  color: #810409;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 55px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1); }
  .button:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1); } 

......

.button {
  border: 3px solid #810409;
  background-color: #FFFCF2;
  color: #810409;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 55px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1); }
  .button:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using CSS modules? If so, you don't need to import your .scss in a main.scss file as you are importing them in your JS file already (otherwise, classes would be duplicated as they are imported in 2 different contexts)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Okey so actually the problem was that I was importing the partial styles in both the partials and main.scss, removed it from main.scss and now it works.